# How to remove a directory that ends with a dot (.) on windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, 7zip, powershell-5.0

I created a file by mistake, and for the life of me, I cannot remove it. If you have [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/a/7z1900-x64.exe) installed, you can produce it. If not, it is easy to install.

Here is how the file gets created:

```
PS C:\temp> mkdir abc
PS C:\temp> cd abc

PS C:\temp\abc> & 'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe' a -spf .\DuoWindowsLogon.admx,.\en-us\DuoWindowsLogon.adml

Creating archive: .\DuoWindowsLogon.admx,.\en-us\DuoWindowsLogon.adml
```

Later, I learned the correct command I should type is:

```
& 'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe' a abc.7z -spf DuoWindowsLogon.admx en-us\DuoWindowsLogon.adml
```

After realizing the error, I tried to remove the directory erroneously created:

```
PS C:\temp\abc> ls
d-----       11/15/2020  11:09 PM                DuoWindowsLogon.admx,.

PS C:\temp\abc> ls D*
ls : Could not find item C:\temp\abc\DuoWindowsLogon.admx,..

PS C:\temp\abc> ls | rm
rm : Cannot find path 'C:\temp\abc\DuoWindowsLogon.admx,.' because it does not exist.

PS C:\temp\abc> rm *
rm : An object at the specified path C:\temp\abc\DuoWindowsLogon.admx,. does not exist.

PS C:\temp\abc> cd ..
PS C:\temp> rm -recurse abc
rm : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\temp\abc\DuoWindowsLogon.admx,'.
```

As you see, nothing worked. I also tried the file explorer (GUI), it does not work either. How can I have the directory deleted?

PS:

I tried "del /s" on CMD prompt, it did not produce an error but the file is not deleted:

```
c:\>del /s c:\temp\abc
c:\temp\abc\*, Are you sure (Y/N)? Y

c:\>dir c:\temp\abc
11/15/2020  11:09 PM    <DIR>          DuoWindowsLogon.admx,.
```

Comment: Try Windows deltree

Comment: My windows 2012R2 does not have deltree. As you can see on the bottom of my post, I did try to delete the parent directory using "Remove-Item" (rm) but it failed.

Comment: Then Try.  del/s

Comment: @Marichyasana It does not work, and I added the screenshot to the end of the post. I believe you can reproduce the problem using the step in the post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can remove the directory that ends with a "." by prefixing it with `\\?\`

So, in your case you can use:

```
Remove-Item `\\?\C:\temp\abc\DuoWindowsLogon.admx,.` -Recurse
```

This is documented here: [You can't delete a file or a folder on an NTFS file system volume](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/backup-and-storage/cannot-delete-file-folder-on-ntfs-file-system)

> You may not be able to delete a file if the file name includes an
> invalid name (for example, the file name has a trailing space or a
> trailing period or the file name is made up of a space only). To
> resolve this issue, use a tool that uses the appropriate internal
> syntax to delete the file. You can use the "`\\?\`" syntax with some
> tools to operate on these files, for example:
>
> ```
> del "\\?\c:\<path_to_file_that contains a trailing space.txt>"
> ```
>
> The cause of this issue is similar to Cause 4. However, if you use
> typical Win32 syntax to open a file that has trailing spaces or
> trailing periods in its name, the trailing spaces or periods are
> stripped before the actual file is opened.

Comment: This worked and I have marked this as the answer, thanks! Why do we need "\\?\" and where is this documented?

Comment: @puravidaso Updated with supporting documentation.

Comment: Thanks. I knew the name was abnormal but did not know the ending dot is the problem, so I could not effectively search. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Worked on Microsoft Windows 11 Pro version 10.0.22621 Build 22621. Make sure to run the command in an elevated Powershell prompt.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, plus an error 0x80004005.

Under Windows10, this worked for me:

```
rd /s "\\?\D:\Folder_1\Folder_2\File_Ending_with_dot."
```